# Failed to load ApplicationContext while running test cases

Tags: java, spring, junit

when i am running my spring integration junit class i am getting above exception.

here is my class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class BpmControllerTest {

    @Autowired
   private BpmProcessorDaoImplTest bpmProcessorDao;  

    @Test
    public void testRun() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException, Exception {
    List<User>user=bpmProcessorDao.testRead();
     Assert.assertEquals(0,user.size());

    }
   }
```

i have my applicationContext inside web-inf and i am using all the spring 4.x jars.

here is my stack trace..

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 37 more
```

can any body please tell me how to write this line

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

some places in google i found like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:**/applicationContext.xml")
```

what is the difference of these two 
and when i am writing this line  with stars i am getting different exception

here is my stack trace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tcs.test.dao.BpmProcessorDaoImplTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 28 more
```

and one thing that my application is only dynamic web project no maven,no ant .
can any body please tell me how to run my test cases successfully..

here is my applicationContext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    ">
         <tx:annotation-driven />
          <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs.test" /> 

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.8.159:1521/OIM.itba.gov.in" />
    <property name="username" value="AppDB"></property>
    <property name="password" value="AppDB"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </bean>     

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>  

   <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.tcs.controller.BpmControllerTest" />
       <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="testRun" cron="0 0/1 * * * ?" />
   </task:scheduled-tasks>  
</beans>
```

all my test java files in side test source folder.
and all the files in side the package's which prefix is com.tcs.test

here is my daoImpl class

```
package com.tcs.test.dao;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tcs.controller.BPMConstants;
import com.tcs.controller.User;

@Repository
public class BpmProcessorDaoImplTest  implements BpmProcessorDaoTest{

    private static final Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(BpmProcessorDaoImplTest. class);


    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    @Test
    public void testWrite() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateStatus() {
    }

    @Test
    public List<User> testRead() {

        String query=null;
        List<User>users=null;

        try{
    //  jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource); 
    //   query=messageSource.getMessage(BPMConstants.QUERY,null,Locale.US);
             query="select taskoutcome,seqNo,hash_mapdata,userid,status,taskId from com_tt_bpm_batch , "
                    + "wftask  where status='ACTIVE' and request_id=instanceid and state='ASSIGNED'";

         logger.info("query");
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(20);


        users=jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<List<User>>(){
             List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public List<User> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
                    while(rs.next()){
                    logger.info("fetching records from db");    
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setTaskOutcome(rs.getString(BPMConstants.TASK_OUTCOME));
                    user.setUserId(rs.getString(BPMConstants.USER_ID));
                    user.setStatus(rs.getString(BPMConstants.STATUS));
                    user.setTaskId(rs.getString(BPMConstants.TASK_ID));
                    user.setSeqNo(rs.getLong(BPMConstants.SEQ_NO));
                    user.setUserComment("nothing");
                    Blob blob=rs.getBlob(BPMConstants.HASH_MAPDATA);
                    try{
                    if(blob!=null && !blob.equals("")){
                    int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
                    byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                    ByteArrayInputStream bos = new ByteArrayInputStream(blobAsBytes);
                    ObjectInputStream out=null;
                        out = new ObjectInputStream(bos);
                    HashMap<String, Object> map=null;
                        map = (HashMap<String, Object>)out.readObject();
                    user.setMap(map);
                    }
                    userList.add(user);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        logger.error(e.getMessage());
                        logger.error("Exception at UserRowMapper class while reading data from blob  "+e.getStackTrace());
                    }
                    }
                return userList;
            }
        });
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Exception at UserRowMapper class while reading data from db  "+e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return users;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does your applicationContext.xml have a bean definition for the `BpmProcessorDaoImplTest`?

Comment: Please share your applicationContext file.

Comment: yes,it is there. i am editing my code please check.

Comment: please share your BpmProcessorDaoImplTest as well.

Comment: In which folder is your `applicaitonContext.xml`... Is it by any change `/WEB-INF`? If so that isn't part of the classpath.

Comment: yes my applicationContext,xml is in side WEB-INF  and please tell me where to keep and how to read

Answer (score 1):

1)

> i have my applicationContext inside web-inf and i am using all the spring 4.x jars.

The `web-inf` folder is not (without hacks and problems) accessabel while running the tests.

So the short and easy solution is to put that spring config files in:

- *(if you use maven):* `src\main\resources`
- *(if you do not use maven):* your java source file root folder
- *(if you do not use maven but eclipse):* create an extra folder (for example `resources`), put the files in that folder, and then make this folder a eclipse source folder (right click that folder in the package explorer and then choose "Build Path" / "Use as Source Folder")

2)
your `BpmProcessorDaoImplTest` does not look like a valid test for me.

Either it is a Test case - then its methods have `@Test` annotations and the class itself have the `@ContextConfiguration` configuration that points to your configuration file. Or is is a Repository then it has a `@Repository` annotation and not `@Test` or `@ContextConfiguration`. annotations. But I never saw a class that mixed this.

So try this:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional //make your tests run in an transaction that gets rolled back after the test
public class BpmProcessorDaoImplTest {

   /** Class under test */
   @Autowired
   private BpmProcessorDao dbmProcessorDao;

   @Autowired
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

   //just to make the example test usefull
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em

   @Test
   public void testWrite() {

      DbmProcessor entity = ...;
      ...
      this.dbmProcessorDao.save();
      ...
      em.flush();  //make sure that every is saved before clear
      em.clear();  //clear to make read(id) read the entity from the database but not from l1-cache.
      int id = entity.getId();          
      ...

      DbmProcessor reloadedEntity = this.dbmProcessorDao.read(id);

      //getName is just an example
      assertEquals(entity.getName(), dbmProcessorDao.getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much for your reply now i am got getting any exception.       but here in my dao class jdbc template and message resource classes are null that means spring is not creating object for that classes.

Comment: Ist is likely that you need to copy the other configration files too.

Comment: i have only one configuration file

Comment: @suri - your test case looks strange, have a look at the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will occure when applicationContext.xml cannot be found in class path

**Possible solutions :**

1. add directory containing **applicationContext.xml** to classpath.
2. give relative path of **applicationContext.xml**
3. give absolute path of **applicationContext.xml**

If 3rd solution worked for you would mean that *applicationContext.xml* was not in classpath.

Comment: hai thanks for your reply , here as i mentioned early i kept my applicationContext,xml inside web-inf then what about class path